# How to combine two different errors

Tags: error, spatial

I have an estimated spatial distribution of gas concentration and its ground truth, and I have compared them on account of two errors: (1) the global error or the error in the concentration values in the Cartesian space, for example, mean squared error (MSE); and (2) the divergence of the probability density function (PDF) of the estimated distribution and the ground truth, for example, Kullback–Leibler divergence (KLD). How to combine both the errors?